# Multithreaded functionality with dynamic data input

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

Im implementing multi threaded functionality using the design pattern discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463266/1581803) and [this blog post](http://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line/).

My data source is dynamic (comes from web POSTs) but all the examples I can find uses a static data source.

My question is therefore: **How can I implement multi threaded functionality with a non-static data input source?**

Example-code:

```
import urllib2 
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 

#  This is a static data source. I need it to be dynamic!
urls = [
  'http://www.python.org', 
  'http://www.python.org/about/',
  # etc.. 
  ]

# Make the Pool of workers
pool = ThreadPool(4) 
# Open the urls in their own threads
# and return the results
results = pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls)
#close the pool and wait for the work to finish 
pool.close() 
pool.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that by non-static you mean a source that produces its items while the workers are already consuming them. It this case, you can use the `Pool.imap()` API and pass a generator instead of a prepared list.

```
import multiprocessing.dummy
import threading


def generate():
    for i in range(20):
        print('generating {}'.format(i))
        yield i


def consume(i):
    print('thread {} consuming {}'.format(threading.current_thread().ident, i))


pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(4)

list(pool.imap(consume, generate()))
```

Be careful to actually consume the iterable that is the return value of the `Pool.imap()` call.